# In laravel blade, array or object

Tags: php, laravel

Array or Object?

In Controller or other layers(Service, Repository...), I never select columns, just

```
Product::where(...)->get();
```

Then in blade

```
{{ $product->name }}
```

Sometimes I add extra columns in Controller, like

```
$product->name = $product->translation->name
```

After php 8.2, dynamic property is deprecated, although we can set AllowDynamicProperties. But maybe this is some kind of rules we better follow/obey in the future ?.

And I think, if don't use toArray(), then the collections contain lots information we don't need.

But I like object format, because we don't need to use quotes. Compare:

```
$product->name
$product['name']
```

Using array, we often need to escape quotes ( ' ) in some situation.

Can I

```
$products = Product::where(...)->get()->toArray();
foreach($products as $product){
    $product['new_column'] = something;
}

$data['products '] = (object) $products;
```

Would it cause any problems?

Comment: Typically do "add" columns for the purposes of presentation you'd use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). Eloquent models also use `__set` to deal with dynamic properties so are not affected by te upcoming 8.2 deprecation

Comment: Do you select columns? Or just use get()?

Comment: It should work either way

Answer (score 1):

I would argue you are really over complicating something that is not that importing for the value proposition this change can provide or not for your end product. For that matter developer experience, we are used to use models.

You can implement a annotation that will remove the deprecation notice.

```
use \AllowDynamicProperties;

#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class Product 
{
```